Integrating Hyperledger fabric and Hyperledger indy
I need to generate a verifiable credential for a digital asset based on some non sensitive information from Hyperledger fabric network . For instance, use api endpoint to pull some reference information from transactions on chain and create a verifiable credential. Is it possible for me to do that?
